# Two of it? Is it correct to say it?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

As I was talking to one of my friends, I said this sentence.

> We will need two of it.

I said it looking at the only glass cup I had. I was preparing for the party.

**Two of it** struck me as extremely wrong. But I knew that I couldn't say "two of these" as there was only one cup in the whole house.

I searched for similar texts but attained no satisfactory results.

I think "two more of it" or "two more of that" is better sounding, but not so sure as to the gramar aspect of it.

Is it grammatical to say "two of it" or "two more of it"?

Comment: I think you meant "...I *heard* this sentence." Anyway, are you looking for "We will need two of *them*"? Two is OK because it is what you *need*, not what you have. You could use *these*, but properly it should modify a noun, like "We will need two of *these glasses*."

Comment: @user3169 So never two of singular? Always two of plural?  I thought when I say _two of these glasses_, it implies that there are more than two glasses and I need only two of those, as opposed to the situation in  which I had only one such glass cup.

Comment: It could mean as you say "there are more than two glasses and I need only two of those". However, with "I need" the one glass is only an example of the kind of object you need. You may or may not have what you "need". If I say "I need a million dollars." it is a good bet that I don't have that much money, right?

Comment: @user3169 Thank you! But I am not questing the use of "two". I don't know why it is licensed to say "two of _THEM_" when there is only one -and no more than one - object that I need two more of. Why use the plural case to address a singular object? It sounds to me like saying "they" when addressing just one person, like saying "they" in place of " you " or "he".

Comment: @P.E.Dant I get it! So _these_ refers to the "two" in _two of these_, not that one cup in my house, right?

Comment: @whitedevil Right! It may be easier to understand if you think of the plurals **them** and **these** in your examples as referring to _the set of all glasses_. A native speaker would, in fact, have said "We will need two of these." Your knowledge of the actual number of cups in your particular house is not a factor. An English speaker might be more specific (and use "two of singular!") by using the phrase "We will need two of **this** cup," but "We will need two of these (cups)" is by far the most natural usage.

Comment: But @PE if (since) *We will need two of this cup* is acceptable, that brings us  back to the question of whether substituting  the singular pronoun *it* for the singular noun phrase *this cup* is correct.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I think that is an English use. But as you are a native speaker of English (I think, judging from your name), I would like to know about your stance on it. For you, is it acceptable?

Comment: @whitedevil I think this is a fantastic question, and I need to do some more research on the expression *two of it*. I may need a few days  to form a decent opinion. *In general*, however, it does sound bad (even very bad) , but it is not ungrammatical; it is more unidiomatic.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Thank you! I will look forward to it :)

Comment: @AlanCarmack This should be interesting. It seems to me that the word "examples" or similar is understood in the sentence _We will need two (examples) of this cup,_ which of course returns us to the plural! Possibly, too, it is just bad grammar on the part of a simple drudge.

Comment: @whitedevil Well, I have searched Google books for "two of it" and "two of it -"or two". The second search eliminates instances of the idiomatic *a  xxxx or two of it*, as in *let me read a page or  two of it,* which is okay. There were a few instances at least one hundred years old like  *We went to the store to buy something we liked and we bought **two of it***, showing that it was considered okay by some people at some point in the past. Also, *two (measure word) of it*, as in *two quarts of it* is fine. So, yeah, I don't think it's ungrammatical, but unidiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example of

> I need two of it

sounds awkward, usually a native will simply say

> I need two
>   I will need two

with surrounding context so that what is needed is understood.

If you are requesting from a large selection of *something* you might say

> I need two of those
>   I need two of these
>   I need two of them

If you are requesting from a single example of *something* you might say

> I need two of this *(while holding an example of what it is you want)*
>   I need two of that *(while pointing to an example of what it is you want)*

Answer (score 1):

One way around your difficulty is a slightly different construction:

> I need two *like* this.

Or

> I need two more *like* this one.